# Bose occupation factor

Tags: statistical-mechanics, terminology, bosons

I am a novice to Bose-Einstein statistics. What is the Bose occupation factor? I understand the terms of statistical mechanics as I am familiar with the Maxwell-Boltzmann statistics.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean $n_i(\epsilon_i,T)=\frac{g_i}{e^{(\epsilon_i-\mu)/k_bT}-1}$, that is just the number of particles in a state of energy $\epsilon_i$, and if you mean $g_i$, that is the degeneracy of such state (number of different wave functions with energy $\epsilon_i$)