# The interpretation of the Bose occupation factor

Tags: energy, solid-state-physics, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, bosons

I was reading into [the Oxford solid state basics, by Steven H.Simon](https://podcasts.ox.ac.uk/series/oxford-solid-state-basics) and I stumbled upon a confusing interpretation of the [Bose Occupation factor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/327296/bose-occupation-factor#327347): $$n_B (x) = \frac{1}{e^x-1}$$ with: $$x = \beta \hbar \omega \ .$$

This result was interpreted as: the mode $\omega$ is an excitation that is excited up to the $n_B^{th}$ level, or that there's a boson orbital which is "occupied by $n_B$ bosons.

Now what I don't understand is, why is the occupation number is being referred to as the energy level when: $$E = n_B\hbar\omega$$ and not: $$E = (n_B + 1/2)\hbar\omega \ .$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Eventually, you're going to take derivatives of the energy to get things like the heat capacity, and the 1/2 term just leads to a constant offset, which goes to zero when you take the derivative.  It's essentially a physically meaningless constant offset that you can ignore.